# Using wildcards in sbt-concat in play framework 2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, sbt-web

I have question concerning the integration of sbt-concat in play framework 2.

I'm using sbt-concat 0.1.8

The file that I want to concatenate are in "javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-ui/theme/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"

Here is my build.sbt

```
name := """training-play"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.33",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
  cache,
  ws
)

Concat.groups := Seq(
  "libs.css" -> group(((resourceDirectory in Assets).value / "javascripts" / "libs" / "jquery" / "jquery-ui" / "theme" / "smoothness") * "*.css"),
  "libs2.css" -> group(Seq("javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-ui/theme/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"))
)

lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("Prints 'Hello World'")

hello := println("hello world!"+(((resourceDirectory in Assets).value / "javascripts" / "libs" / "jquery" / "jquery-ui" / "theme" / "smoothness") * "*.css"))


pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(concat)
```

The "hello" task show me that my PathFinder is pointing to the correct file, but the file libs.css is never created (libs2.css is working fine).

Does someone know how to make it works correctly ?